# Not able to fetch data from https web api

Tags: json, security, grails, https

Exception in thread "main"

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

anyone have face this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Compile & run java class
https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java

2.Run java InstallCert

3.It will fetch the certificates & create a new file "jssecacerts" on desktop.

4.Copy paste this file to /javaHome/jre/lib/security.

5.Now you can hit the https web api.

Similar you have to do on live server where you will deploy the webApp.